# SQLite selecting all from multiple tables and reading from cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I have a query which retrieves data from different tables

```
select * from customer c, order o where c.id = o.pID
```

both tables have a column 'date_created' and i want to retrieve the date_created from order table

I tried `Cursor c = db.execute(sql); String dateCreated = c.getString("date_created")` which returned the customer date and not the order date. when i try `c.getString("o.date_created")` my app crashes and returns "E/SQLiteCursor: requesting column name with table name -- o.date_created
java.lang.Exception"

can someone please guide me on how i can get the order date_created?
I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select *, c.date_created as customer_date_created, o.date_created as order_date_created from customer c, order o where c.id = o.pID
```

then just use:

```
c.getString("order_date_created");
```

Comment: that works but is there a way to get a field from a specific table without listing out all the columns because in my actual code I have 5 tables each having more than 6 columns

Comment: If the columns are using the same name I don't think there is other option than giving aliases for those columns or running the selections on different queries (which maybe create a performance and maintenance overhead).

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate the column name by using Alias name as below:

```
select c.date_created as cust_date, o.date_created as order_date from customer c, order o where c.id = o.pID
```

Then try:

```
c.getString("order_date");
```

Answer (score 1):

The resultset of your query contains 2 columns with the same name, so when you try to retrieve the column by the name `date_created` you can't be sure which one you get.
This is why you must use aliases for all columns that have the same name:

```
select c.column1, c.column2, c.date_created as cust_date_created, .....
       o.column1, o.column2, o.date_created as ord_date_created, ....
from customer c inner join [order] o 
on c.id = o.pID
```

You can omit the columns that you don't want in the results.
Also use proper join syntax.

Now you can get the column's value by:

```
String dateCreated = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ord_date_created"))
```